# Grep to count occurrences of file A in file B

Tags: count, grep

I have two files, file A may be in file B and I would like to count for each line in file A, how many times it occurs in file B. For example:

File A:

```
GAGGACAGACTACTAAAGCC
CTTGCCGCAGATTATCAGAG
CCAGCTTGATGTGTCCTGTG
TGATAGGCAGTGGAACACTG
```

File B:

```
NTCTTGAGGAAAGGACGAATCTGCGGAGGACAGACTACTAAAGCCGTTTGAGAGCTAGAACGAGCAAGTTAAGAGA
TCTTGAGGAAAGGACGAAACTCCGGAGGACAGACTACTAAAGCCGTTTTAGAGCTAGAAAGCGCAAGTTAAACGAC
NTCTTGAGGAAAGGACGAATCTGCGCTTGCCGCAGATTATCAGAGGTATGAGAGCTAGAACGAGCAAGTTAAGAGC
TCTTGAGGAAAGGACGAAAGTGCGCTTGCCGCAGATTATCAGAGGTTTTAGAGCTAGAAAGAGCAAGTTAAAATAA
GATCTAGTGGAAAGGACGATTCTCCGCTTGCCGCAGATTATCAGAGGTTGTAGAGCTAGAACTAGCAAGTGACAAG
ATCTTGAGGAAAGGACGAATCTGCGCTTGCCGCAGATTATCAGAGGTTTGAGAGCTAGAACTAGCAAGTTAATAGA
CGATCAAGTGGAAGGACGATTCTCCGTGATAGGCAGTGGAACACTGGATGTAGAGCTAGAAATAGCAAGTGAGCAG
ATCTAGAGGAAAGGACGAATCTCCGTGATAGGCAGTGGAACACTGGTATGAGAGCTAGAACTAGCAAGTTAATAGA
TCTTGAGGAAAGGACGAAACTCCGTGATAGGCAGTGGAACACTGGTTTTAGAGCTAGAAAGCGCAAGTTAAAAGAC
```

And the output should be File C:

```
2 GAGGACAGACTACTAAAGCC
4 CTTGCCGCAGATTATCAGAG
0 CCAGCTTGATGTGTCCTGTG
3 TGATAGGCAGTGGAACACTG
```

I would like to do this using grep and I've tried a few variations of -c,o,f but I can't seem to get the right output.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for i in `cat a`; do echo "$i  `grep $i -c b`"; done
```

In this case if line from file A occurred several times in one line of file B then this will be count as one occurrence. If you want to count such occurrences but without its overlapping use this

```
for i in `cat a`; do printf $i; grep $i -o b | wc -l; done
```

And maybe this variant would be quicker

```
cat b | grep "`cat a`" -o | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: thanks, this works but it's really slow. Any ideas how to speed it up? My fileA is hundreds of lines long and fileB is millions of lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open A, "A";                   # open file "A" to handle A
open B, "B";                   # open file "B" to handle B
chomp(@keys = <A>);            # read keys to array, strip line-feeds
@counts{@keys} = (0) x @keys;  # initialize hash counts for keys
while(<B>){                    # iterate file handle B line by line
    foreach $k (@keys){        # iterate keys array
        if (/$k/) {            # if key matches line
            $counts{$k}++;     # increase count for key by one
        }
    }
}
print "$counts{$_} $_\n" for (keys %counts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux command to compare files:

```
comm FileA FileB
```

`comm` produces three-column output. Column one contains lines unique to `FileA`, column two contains lines unique to `FileB`, and column three contains lines common to both files.